# Separating lines disappear when I choose adjacent cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a piece of code as follows (I have omitted the unnecessary parts):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as PFTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero) 
    return cell
}
```

When I choose adjacent cells, the separating line between them disappears, which is not what I want. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: Why do you set the table view's properties over and over again every time a cell is requested? Set those properties once. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function should only create, configure, and return a single cell, not set properties of the table view.

Answer (score 1):

When you select any cell separator disappears. The solution is to add custom separators.

Answer (score 0):

Try move the code below to viewDidLoad as it just need to be executed once:

```
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame:CGRectZero)
```

Comment: The `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` function is to indicate whether the row shows the delete or insert icons or not. That's it.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks I may have been use it in the wrong way. I remove that comment from the post